# Scraping GPU data seems taking too long

Tags: php, web-scraping

so in my spare time I wanted to make a web to track the GPU price on a e-commerce. I am using PHP and the library Simple HTML DOM to parse the target HTML and it happen every hour from CRON Job.

(*Yes, I knew I can make it in Selenium or others to scrape data more efficiently, but in this case just to challenge myself while learning it*).

How it work is : Grab data and store it into database. Next, in other table it matches data from database : When the new price of a GPU is the same as latest price, it just update the date and time; If the new price is different with the latest, it make the latest price into old price and update some other things.

- The scraping things is coded for a specific e-commerce website;
- These variables placement are still scattered a little bit because I tried other
  things;
- It grab data every hour and logs the seconds on average 40-50, so my assumption is this processing time.

My question is : **How can I make the code more efficient compared to my current method?**

This is the code to grab the data :

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);

require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

// Database variables here
// ...

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
  // Get the URL List
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,url FROM url_list");
  $stmt->execute();
  $url_list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
  
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// Scrap the data from a website then return as array
function get_gpu_info(string $targeturl, int $gpu_id)
{
    $results = array();
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($targeturl);
    
    if (!empty($html)) {
    $div_class = $price = $stock = "";
    
    $div_class = $html->find("#main-pdp-container", 0);
        $out_of_stock = $html->find(".css-1igct5v-unf-quantity-editor__input[disabled]", 0); 
        $price = $div_class->find(".price", 0)->innertext;
        $price_int = intval(preg_replace('/[^\d\,]+/', '', $price));
        $stock = ($div_class->find(".css-1a29oke p b", 0)->innertext) ?: 0; 
    
        if (!empty($price)) {
            $results = array(
                'GPUID' => $gpu_id,
                'PRICE' => $price,
                'PRICEINT' => $price_int,
                'STOCK' => $stock
                );
        } else {echo "Price not found";}
    } else {echo "URL Not Found";}

    return $results;
}

// Scrap every single data from the URL list found
$gpu_data = array_map('get_gpu_info', array_values($url_list), array_keys($url_list));

try {
    $time = date("H:i:s");
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO price_history (gpu_id, price, price_int, stock, update_time, update_date) 
        VALUES (:insert_gpu_id, :insert_price, :insert_price_int, :insert_stock, :insert_update_time, :insert_update_date)");
    
    $stmt->bindParam(':insert_gpu_id', $insert_gpu_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':insert_price', $insert_price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':insert_price_int', $insert_price_int);
    $stmt->bindParam(':insert_stock', $insert_stock);
    $stmt->bindParam(':insert_update_time', $time);
    $stmt->bindParam(':insert_update_date', $date);
    
    foreach ($gpu_data as $data => $val) {
        $insert_gpu_id = $val['GPUID'];
        $insert_price = $val['PRICE'];
        $insert_price_int = $val['PRICEINT'];
        $insert_stock = $val['STOCK'];
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(gpu_id) FROM gpu_data WHERE gpu_id = :gpu_id");
        $stmt2->bindValue(':gpu_id', $val['GPUID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $count = (int)$stmt2->fetchColumn();
        
        if($count) { 
            $stmt4 = $conn->prepare("SELECT old_price, old_price_int, latest_price, latest_price_int, latest_update_time, latest_update_date FROM gpu_data WHERE gpu_id = :gpu_id");
            $stmt4->bindParam(':gpu_id', $val['GPUID']);
            $stmt4->execute();
            $old_data = $stmt4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
            $old_price_int = $old_data['old_price_int'];
            $old_latest_price_int = $old_data['latest_price_int'];
            $old_price = $old_data['old_price'];
            $get_date = $old_data['latest_update_date'];
            $get_time = $old_data['latest_update_time'];
            $combined_old_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$get_date $get_time"));
            
            if($old_price_int == $insert_price_int) { 
                //print_r("Same price");
                $stmt3 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE gpu_data SET 
                stock = :stock, 
                latest_update_time = :update_time, 
                latest_update_date = :update_date 
                WHERE gpu_id = :gpu_id");
                
            } else {
                //print_r("Different price");
                
                $stmt3 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE gpu_data SET 
                old_price = :old_price,
                old_price_int = :old_price_int, 
                old_datetime = :old_datetime, 
                latest_price = :price, 
                latest_price_int = :price_int, 
                stock = :stock, 
                latest_update_time = :update_time, 
                latest_update_date = :update_date 
                WHERE gpu_id = :gpu_id");
                
                $stmt3->bindParam(':old_price', $old_price);
                $stmt3->bindParam(':old_price_int', $old_price_int);
                $stmt3->bindParam(':old_datetime', $combined_old_date_time);
                $stmt3->bindParam(':price', $insert_price);
                $stmt3->bindParam(':price_int', $insert_price_int);
                
                print_r("Old price updated");
            }
            
            $stmt3->bindParam(':update_time', $time);
            $stmt3->bindParam(':update_date', $date);
            $stmt3->bindParam(':stock', $insert_stock);
            $stmt3->bindParam(':gpu_id', $val['GPUID']);
            
            $stmt3->execute();
            
            //print_r("GPU Data with the same record found and has been updated");
        } else {//print_r("ERROR: No GPU Data with that GPU ID has been found");
        }
    }
    //print_r("Price record/s updated successfully");

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which of these parts is slow? Is it the database part itself, or any other? Something like XDebug's profiler, or Blackfire can help you to check that. Identifying the slow part is the first neccessary step to recommend improvements

Comment: If you want people to review your existing code, then I suggest you move your question to codereview.stackexchange.com sister site of SO.

Comment: Thank you Nico Haase. I'll try those!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're taking a lot of time to load each page you're scraping. Probably some pages are a lot slower than others. Try doing something like this, to time your `load_file()` operations, to figure that out.

```php
$loadStartTime = date();
$html->load_file($targeturl);
$loadEndTime = date();
echo $targeturl . ': ' . $loadEndTime - $loadStartTime . ' seconds to load.';
```

Your dom-romping code looks straightforward enough.

It seems doubtful you have many thousands of rows in your table, so your database stuff should be fast enough.